# How to fix the AWS Lambda nodejs8.10 is no longer supported error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have the following error message when my deployment script runs to deploy to aws lambda.  I've updated the node version as shown in the screen shot below, it confirms I've changed node to version 12.x.

Not sure why I'm still getting this error message? :-(

[image: lambda panel showing node has been updated]

**error message**

> Error: deploying: eu-west-1: updating function config: InvalidParameterValueException: The runtime parameter of nodejs8.10 is
>   no longer supported for creating or updating AWS Lambda functions. We
>   recommend you use the new runtime (nodejs12.x) while creating or
>   updating functions.

**deployment script**

```
#!/bin/bash
yarn
# deploy
/tmp/up/up deploy staging
```

**possible solution?**

I've seen this in documentation but having done the above I was under the impression I don't need to do this..?

> aws lambda update-function-configuration --function-name
>    --layers
>   arn:aws:lambda::800406105498:layer:nsolid-node-10:6
>   --runtime provided

Documentation available here -> https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/node-js-6-is-approaching-end-of-life-upgrade-your-aws-lambda-functions-to-the-node-js-10-lts/

Comment: I would assume that somehow Lambda is seeing nodejs8.10 in your UpdateFunctionConfiguration request. You should be able to see this in CloudTrail, for confirmation.

Comment: What does `deploy staging` do? It sounds like something in your deploy script is setting the version to 8.10.

Comment: looking at CloudTrail for the first time and clicking on 'view event' I can't see anything in the modal window that displays within aws that refers to the version of node @jarmod?

Comment: Hi @Jack are you using `up` ( https://apex.sh/docs/up/ ), if you are can you check the runtime in your lambda settings ?

Comment: bang on, thanks!  Post this as an answer!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you using `up`( [docs](https://apex.sh/docs/up) ), if you are can you check the runtime in your lambda settings and change the runtime there.

Thx!